# jQuery if (x == y) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So, I have some faux checkboxes (so I could style them) that work with jQuery to act as checked or not checked. There are a number of faux checkboxes in my document, and for each one I have a click function:

```
var productInterest = [];
productInterest[0] = false;
productInterest[1] = false;
productInterest[2] = false;

// here is one function of the three:

$('#productOne').click(function() {
    if (productInterest[0] == false) {
        $(this).addClass("checkboxChecked");
        productInterest[0] = true;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("checkboxChecked");
        productInterest[0] = false;
    }
});
```

The problem seems to be that there is an error in the if statement, because it will check, but not uncheck. In other words it will add the class, but the variable won't change so it still thinks its checked. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** So, I need to show you all my code because it works in the way I supplied it (thanks commenters for helping me realize that)... just not in the way its actually being used on my site. so below please find the code in its entirety.

Everything needs to happen in one function, because the UI and data for each checkbox need to be updated at once. So here is the complete function:

```
$('input[name=silkInterest]').click(function() { // they all have the same name

    var silkInterest = [];
    silkInterest[0] = false;
    silkInterest[1] = false;
    silkInterest[2] = false;

    if ($(this).is('#silkSilk')) { // function stops working because the .is()
        if (silkInterest[0] == false) {
            $(this).addClass("checkboxChecked");
            silkInterest[0] = true;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("checkboxChecked");
            silkInterest[0] = false;
        }
        alert(silkInterest[0]);
    }
    if ($(this).is('#silkAlmond')) {
        if (silkInterest[1] == false) {
            $(this).addClass("checkboxChecked");
            silkInterest[1] = true;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("checkboxChecked");
            silkInterest[1] = false;
        }
    }
    if ($(this).is('#silkCoconut')) {
        if (silkInterest[2] == false) {
            $(this).addClass("checkboxChecked");
            silkInterest[2] = true;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("checkboxChecked");
            silkInterest[2] = false;
        }
    }

    var silkInterestString = silkInterest.toString();
    $('input[name=silkInterestAnswer]').val(silkInterestString);
    // This last bit puts the code into a hidden field so I can capture it with php.

});
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. (although you really should be using a loop for that, rather than copy pasting 3 times)

Comment: Try alerting the value after the click event fires to see whether it's actually been changed.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it worked just fine.  Perhaps another piece of code on the page is malformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just had a palm to forehead moment. In regards to my revised code- the variables get reset everytime I click. That was the problem. Duh.

Answer (score 3):

I can't spot the problem in your code, but you can simply use the class you're adding in place of the `productInterest` array. This lets you condense the code down to a single:

```
// Condense productOne, productTwo, etc...
$('[id^="product"]').click(function() {
    // Condense addClass, removeClass
    $(this).toggleClass('checkboxChecked');
});
```

And to check if one of them is checked:

```
if ($('#productOne').hasClass('checkboxChecked')) {...}
```

This'll make sure the UI is always synced to the "data", so if there's other code that's interfering you'll be able to spot it.

Comment: That solution works great, but as you mentioned keeping the UI synced with the data is important. As a result everything should be contained in one function so that if any checkbox is checked, the UI and the data gets updated at once. 

Commenters above noted that the code works the way I supplied it in the question- true enough apparently. But I was trying to paraphrase the code to avoid a huge block of code. My code above stops working when I use an if (x).is(y) before each function.

Comment: Please see my updated question at the top... thanks for your help Box9.

Comment: @inorganik, the # is for IDs, whereas you have names. Use `"[name=silkSilk]"` instead.

Comment: I know what the # is for, I intentionally used IDs because all of those checkboxes use the same name, because they are all part of the same question. Reason being because of the way I "harvest" the information with php.